# Можно ли задать названия изображение на кирилице?

Tags: html, вёрстка, img

Верстка. Есть около 18 изображений, названия на русском. Не хочу менять, иконки марок , не сильно отличаются, могу напутать. Критично

```
<img src='path/to/изображение.png'>
```

Comment: Теоретически, нужно преобразовать ссылки в нечто похожее `%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.png`, практически - всё скорее всего и так будет работать.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что всё зависит от сервера, на котором будут хоститься эти картинки и лежать html-файлы.
Я сталкивался с такой проблемой, что загрузить на сервер файлы с названиями такими я мог, видел их там, а удалить или обратиться к ним - не мог. Жесть ситуация.
Поэтому переименовывай, и не создавай себе риски на будущее. Ни для стиля кода, ни для SEO это не важно, а гимор может создать. 
Лучше title заполни для изображений, на русском.

Comment: Если сервер не умеет в юникод — валить надо с такого сервера подальше

Answer (score 0):

Можно, но лучше не надо
При переносах между системами могут возникнуть разные сайд еффекты, есть вероятность что сервер на которым ты это будеш делать не будет работать с кирилицей и потом он просто не будет видеть эти изображения. Так что лучше не пиши на кирилице и переименуй их.

Comment: То же самое: если сервер не умеет в юникод — валить надо с такого сервера подальше